# combine multiple jq commands into one?

Tags: jq

I use the following command to extract data from a json file. Suppose that I just keep the first match if there is a match. (If there is no match, an error should be printed.)

```
.[] | select(.[1] | objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog") | .[1]."/Dests"
```

Let's say the output is 16876. Then, I use the following jq code to extract the data.

```
.[] | select(.[0] == 16876) | .[1] | to_entries[] | [.key, .value[0], .value[2].F, .value[3].F] | @tsv
```

This involves multiple passes of the input json data. Can the two jq commands be combined into one, so that one pass of the input json data is sufficient?

Comment: Hint: `as $varname` is your friend.

Comment: BTW, if you don't provide a [mre] with sample input that causes the stated output, nobody can test their answers, or prove/disprove whether someone else's answer was correct.

Comment: If you need to perform this repeatedly, consider building up an index on `.[0]` (e.g. using `INDEX(.[0])`), so you don't have to search through the whole array over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as $dests` to bind the results of your first query branch to the name `$dests`, and then refer back to those results in the second branch within a single copy of `jq`.

```
(.[] | select(.[1] | objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog") | .[1]."/Dests") as $dests
| .[] | select(.[0] == $dests) | .[1] | to_entries[] | [.key, .value[0], .value[2].F, .value[3].F] | @tsv
```