# Is jq speed limited by preprocessing the input data?

Tags: jq

I use the code to find in three steps: 1) find the objects of an array, 2) then see if the object contain the name "/Root", 3) if so print the first value of "/Root" then exit.

```
first(.[][1] | objects | select(."/Root" != null) | ."/Root")
```

The actual input is very long. But the result is in the first few lines of the input. If I use awk to extract the data, it should be very quick (definitely less than 1 sec). But the above jq code takes 10 seconds to finish.

Does jq always read all input before it can produce any result?

Is it possible to make jq as fast as awk for cases like this where there data to be extract is at the beginning of the input?

Comment: Can you show a _simplified_ input file?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. Your question does not make it clear whether the input you have in mind is a single JSON entity or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your first general question is:

> Does jq always read all input before it can produce any result?

The general answer is: yes, if you use jq's default parser, then an entire JSON entity will be read; and no, if you use jq's streaming parser, since you can in that case short-circuit the reading of the input, e.g. using `limit` or `first`.

Your second general question is:

> Is it possible to make jq as fast as awk for cases like this where there data to be extract is at the beginning of the input?

The general answer is: no, since in cases like this, jq must do at least some JSON parsing.

In general, if you want to use jq and obtain awk-like speeds for the type of problem you describe, you'd have to pre-process the large file (e.g. with jj or [jm or jm.py](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm)) so that jq can do its thing.

For example, you could use [jj](https://github.com/tidwall/jj) (specifically `jj -l`) in conjunction with `jq`.  The -l option has the effect of "splatting" the top-level array.

---

Footnote: I mention jj in particular here as it can also be used to obtain the very last item in an array very quickly: `jj -l '@reverse.0'`.  This is not obvious as `@reverse` itself is slow; evidently there's some under-the-hood optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The following streaming solution should work:

```
<input.json jq --stream 'select(.[0][1:] == [1, "/Root"])[1] | values' | head -1
```

([`values`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars) is [short for](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L63) `select(. != null)`)

Using only jqs:

```
<input.json jq --stream 'select(.[0][1:] == [1, "/Root"])[1] | values' | jq -n 'input'
```

More streaming goodness:

```
<input.json jq --stream -n 'limit(1; fromstream(2 | truncate_stream(inputs))."/Root" | values)'
```

or

```
<input.json jq --stream -n 'first(fromstream(2 | truncate_stream(inputs))."/Root" | values))'
```

Comment: `values` is [defined](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L63) as `select(. != null)`, so using `select(values)` makes no sense. Just use `values`.

Comment: @pmf whoops, double trouble! Fixed the post, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: The last part of this answer (using `first` with —stream) is right on. The rest is irrelevant and distracting, which is a shame.

Comment: @peak there is no `first` in my answer. Did you mean `limit(1; …)`? I still find it valuable to provide alternatives, especially since the last variant is the least understandable for newcomers. And if it works, it ain't stupid, right? ;) merry christmas!

Comment: @knittl -  As you know, `first` is shorthand for `limit(1; …)`. The “alternatives” in this case don’t answer the Q and detract from your answer, so I’d either delete them, or use them in an explanation of the real answer. HNY!

Comment: The doc on [streaming](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) is not very clear. What does "The examples below use the streamed form of [0,[1]], which is [[0],0],[[1,0],1],[[1,0]],[[1]]." mean? Which examples? All the examles below? What is the streamed form of [0, [1]]?

Comment: If --stream is used, then it will not work for the following question which combines commands that just find the first match and the ones that don't? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74905435/combine-multiple-jq-commands-into-one

Comment: @user119720 I can't speak for the other question because it does not contain an [mre]. There's no sample output and no expected output. People will not spend time trying to come up with example inputs that might or might not match your data.

Comment: My last question is a general one on when --stream is applicable, which does not depend on specific exsamples. The doc is not clear on it. But base on the idea that stream means pass the input once and stop immediately once a result is found, it sounds like if there are other operations that require the whole input, --stream would not be appropriate to be used.

Comment: @user119720 `--stream` can be used with any input. It will produce `[path, leaf-value]` pairs for leaf-values and `[path]` when an object is "closed" (its last leaf was written). It uses less memory because it can _stream_ the input, without loading the full file into memory first. But it comes at a cost: the stream is more difficult to filter and transform. The manual uses the input `[0,[1]]` (or its streamed form) for all stream-related examples. Try it yourself: `printf '[0,[1]]' | jq -c --stream '.'`

Comment: I got `$ printf '[0,[1]]' | jq -c --stream '.'
[[0],0]
[[1,0],1]
[[1,0]]
[[1]]` which is different from `$ jq -c . <<< '[0,[1]]'
[0,[1]]`. But I don't get what the output of --stream one is. How can I understand what it means?

Comment: @user119720 I really don't know how to explain it better, sorry. `--stream` produces `[path, leaf-value]` (which is documented in the manual). `path` is the path to the value and `leaf-value` is the value. `[[0], 42]` meaning the value 42 is in the array at index 0. `[[1,0], 21]` means that the value 21 is at index/location `.[1][0]`, and so on. And of course the output of jq with and without `--stream` will be different, it's a totally different operation mode.